# I am having issues using Regex to parse a chat and turn it into a dataframe. - it is just skipping info

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I am creating a function to parse the copied chat from a yahoo fantasy mock draft and turn it into a dataframe of drafted players. It seems to skip lines for reasons I cannot determine. I am using python and using the pandas and regex (re) libraries. The input is a multi-line string copied and pasted from the chat.

Here is a small sample input with some edge cases that were causing issues. I am pretty sure the issue lies in the patter variable with all the regex code.

Sample Input:

```
chat_str2 = """
12thJ. JacobsLV - RB

13thS. DiggsBuf - WR

14thD. AdamsLV - WR

19thA. St. BrownDet - WR

97thJ. Smith-NjigbaSea - WR

120thMiamiMia - DEF"""
```

Here is the function I have thus far. It works well but randomly is skipping lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def parse_draft_data(data_string):
    team_abrev = ["Ari","Atl","Bal","Buf","Car","Chi","Cin","Cle","Dal","Den","Det","GB","Hou","Ind","Jax","KC","LAC","LAR","LV","Mia","Min","NE","NO","NYG","NYJ","Phi","Pit","Sea","SF","TB","Ten","Was"]
    pos_abrev = ["QB", "RB", "WR", "TE", "K", "DEF"]

    pattern = r"(\d+)(?:th|st|nd|rd)?(?:([A-Z])\.\s*)?([\w\s-]+?)\s*(" + "|".join(team_abrev) + r")\s*-\s*(" + "|".join(pos_abrev) + r")"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, data_string)

    data = {
        "draft_num": [],
        "first_initial": [],
        "last_name": [],
        "team": [],
        "pos": []
    }

    for match in matches:
        draft_num, first_initial, last_name, team, pos = match
        data["draft_num"].append(int(draft_num))
        data["first_initial"].append(first_initial if first_initial else None)
        data["last_name"].append(last_name.strip())
        data["team"].append(team)
        data["pos"].append(pos)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df["team"] = df["team"].str.strip()
    return df
```

It is skipping lines for some reason that I cannot determine. In the above input it is skipping the line with "19thA. St. BrownDet - WR". This is the output I am receiving using the above input and fucntion:

Output:

```
   draft_num first_initial     last_name team  pos
0         12             J        Jacobs   LV   RB
1         13             S         Diggs  Buf   WR
2         14             D         Adams   LV   WR
3         97             J  Smith-Njigba  Sea   WR
4        120          None         Miami  Mia  DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/44Dqr1/1)):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd


chat_str2 = """
12thJ. JacobsLV - RB

13thS. DiggsBuf - WR

14thD. AdamsLV - WR

19thA. St. BrownDet - WR

97thJ. Smith-NjigbaSea - WR

120thMiamiMia - DEF"""

pat = re.compile(r"^(\d+).*?(?:([A-Z])\.\s*)?([A-Z].*)([A-Z]\S+) - (.*)", flags=re.M)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    pat.findall(chat_str2),
    columns=["draft_num", "first_initial", "last_name", "team", "pos"],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  draft_num first_initial     last_name team  pos
0        12             J        Jacobs   LV   RB
1        13             S         Diggs  Buf   WR
2        14             D         Adams   LV   WR
3        19             A     St. Brown  Det   WR
4        97             J  Smith-Njigba  Sea   WR
5       120                       Miami  Mia  DEF
```

Comment: Wow this is a great solution much more streamlined - thank you so much!